# ReduxForm Field component not working with ReactTable Cell property in column Headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

In ReactTable, I want to render my own `Checkbox` component using `Field` from `redux-form` through the `Cell` renderer of `react-table`.

But I'm getting a getting this error:

`Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

I don't know why.

Check my code:

```
import { Field } from 'redux-form';
import Checkbox from 'Components/Checkbox';

const setTableColumns = () => {
  return [
    {
      Header: 'Entities',
      accessor: 'target',
      Cell: rowData => (
        <span className="RoleTarget" key={rowData.original.target}>
          <AllCheckerCheckbox
            name={`CheckAll-${rowData.original.userId}`}
            id={rowData.original.userId}
          />
          <span className="RoleTarget__name">{rowData.original.target}</span>
        </span>
      ),
      width: 190,
    },
    {
      Header: 'Add',
      accessor: 'add',
      Cell: rowData => {
        // Problematic code below.
        return <Field name="ADD" component={Checkbox} type="checkbox"  />;
      },
      minWidth: 60,
    },
  ]
}

export default setTableColumns
```

Also outside the table, `Field` component works fine! It's only inside the table that causes trouble. Can someone tell me what going on between `react-table` and `redux-form`, and how to make them work together?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

what links a Field to the redux-form store is the 'name' prop. In the case of an [Array of Fields](http://%5Bhttps://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/fieldarrays/) it should be something like name={`${member}.ADD`}.

So you need to render your table inside a FieldArray:

<FieldArray
name=`your-array-of-fields-in-redux-form`
component={`renderTable`}
columns={`renderTable`}>

Redux-form will pass to `renderTable` the `fields` prop, which you can use to hidrate the `data` props you pass to react-table (with the field names and respective values).

```
const renderCellField = ({ input, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }, ...custom) => (
    <div>
      <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label} />
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
)

const renderTable = ({fields, columns}) => {
  // console.log(equipments)
  return(
  <Table columns={columns} data={fields.map((name, index, fields)=>({...fields.get(index), id:name})
  )}/>
)}

class MyTable extends React.Component{
  render() {
    let columns = [
      { (...)

        Header: 'Select',
        accessor: 'selected',
        Cell: (row: any) => {
          return(
            <Field
              name={`${row.row.original.id}.selected`}
              component={renderCellField}
              type="checkbox"
              placeholder="Enter equipment name"
            />
          );
        }
      },
    ]
    return(
      <FieldArray name="equipments" component={renderTable} columns={columns}/>
    )
  }
}


export default reduxForm({
  form: 'creatInstallForm',
  fields: ['equipments'],
})(MyTable)
```